# Graded readers for Polish?

Tags: electronic-resources, physical-resources, graded-readers, polish

As I have already mentioned in several other questions, graded readers are a good resources for [extensive reading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensive_reading), at least for people who are not yet sufficiently proficient to read texts written for native speakers of the target language.

[Polish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_language) is a language with 40 million native speakers, so it is among the bigger ones in the European Union. Hence the question: are there any graded readers for Polish?

Answer (score 3):

Yes there are several:

- [Here](http://lppbooks.com/Polish/FirstPolishReader_audio/En/index.html) [is](http://lppbooks.com/Polish/FirstPolishReaderV2/En/index.html) [a](http://lppbooks.com/Polish/FirstPolishReaderV3/En/index.html) [series](http://lppbooks.com/Polish/SecondPolishReader_audio/En/index.html) of four.
- [Polish Easy Readers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0147L2UQO)
- [Graded Classic Polish Literature](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0781803268)